# Durandal Navigation without using "router"

Tags: knockout.js, url-routing, single-page-application, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I am developing a CMS using Durandal. My problem is with navigating through my menu items and other links. These pages don't "exist" hence am not sure how to map them for routing purposes. The starterkit on Durandal make reference to static pages. For development purposes I was manually typing the url. Is there a way I can create a route mechanism to retrieve HTML pages stored in the database - for navigation purposes? Any ideas and pointers welcome?

Comment: When you say "...which I get from the database using ajax," are you referring to the page itself or a route to the page?  In other words, are you simply looking to store the routes to your pages in a database, or are you looking to store the pages themselves in a database?

Comment: @EricTaylor I have edited my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was use durandal [Route Parameters and Query Strings](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html).